# Verb Tenses and Auxiliary Verbs

Tags: verbs, tenses, auxiliary-verbs, context

> Our train leaves at four-thirty tomorrow morning.

This is probably a simple problem, but I am having difficultly finding a source that answers my specific question. I am having some trouble determining the tense of *leaves* here, and determining tenses in general. The sources (here's [one example](https://www.uhv.edu/student-success-center/resources/q-z/understanding-verbs-verb-tenses/), but I am referring to basic guides) I have read imply that a lack of any auxiliary verbs (beyond *will* for future simple) automatically indicate simple tense. Is this true? For example, *leaves* is present tense on its own. However, in the context of this sentence, the train is clearly departing at a specific time in the future.

How do I determine the tense? Is it present simple because there are no auxiliary verbs, and *leaves* on its own is present, or is it future perfect because it "describes an action that will be completed by a specific time in the future." Is it neither?

Does the context of a sentence change the tense of a verb like this? Or am I entirely off the mark in how I'm determining tense? Grammar resources like the one I linked are useful, but I am still finding myself lost. Any links to more exhaustive and nuanced explanations/resources would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the word *tense* is defined differently in different resources. In the one you link to *tense* refers to all possible combinations of time frame (*past, present*,  *future*) and aspect (*simple, progressive, perfect*).

By this definition the *present simple* is a tense, as is the *present perfect simple*, and the *present perfect progressive*, and the *future perfect progressive*, and so on.

This conception of tense is common in pedagogic (prescriptive) materials for English language learners. However, *tense* as defined in authoritative descriptive grammars such as *Oxford Modern English Grammar* is restricted to just *present* and *past*:

> It must be said at the outset that the inflectional system of tense in
>   English is quite simple in allowing only a present tense and a past
>   tense. English has no future tense, because it has no future tense
>   inflections, in the way other language do, nor any other grammatical
>   form or combination of forms that can be exclusively called a future
>   tense. (p243)

Whichever definition you adopt, however, you should abandon the belief that the name of the tense determines its use; that, for example, a present tense can only be used to talk about a presently occuring event or state. In fact, the various tenses (first definition) can have various functions.

In your sentence *Our train leaves at four-thirty tomorrow morning* '*leaves*' is in the present tense simple form (i.e. there is no auxiliary). One function of the present simple is to refer to a future scheduled event. The present tense can also be used when talking about the past (also called the *historical present*). It is common in narratives:

> "So he walks over to me and he gets right beside me and leans down and
>   he just whispers to me, he goes 'Timmy, he just doesn't understand.'"
>   [Source](https://247sports.com/college/florida/Bolt/Tebow-shares-terrific-T-ball-story-with-Le-Batard-47483552)

As to the past simple form, one of its functions is to express a counterfactual. For example, *If I had a lot of money ...*. This is a reference to the present despite the use of the past tense.

For more information on tense, with some good extracts from authoritative resources, I recommend *[Understanding Verb Tenses](https://www.thoughtco.com/tense-grammar-1692532)* at *ThoughtCo*.

Comment: A balanced treatment. A rarity.

Answer (score 0):

We use the present simple tense for future ( planned ) events. https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/

http://www.grammaring.com/present-simple-for-fixed-future-events-schedules-timetables-and-itineraries

http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/english-grammar-how-to-use-the-present-simple-to-talk-about-future-events/